Issue with Footnotes Display in PhpWord
When attempting to add multiple footnotes in close proximity within a PhpWord document, only the second footnote appears at the bottom of the page. The first footnote does not display properly.
Even when i add single footnote then also first footnote is not showing at bottom of page
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$footercellStyle = ['name' => 'Calibri', 'size' => 10];
$paragraphStyle = [
    'alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::LEFT,
    'spaceAfter' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pointToTwip(1),
    'spaceBefore' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pointToTwip(1)
];

// Example of multiple footnotes
$footnotes = [
    "First footnote text.",
    "Second footnote text.",
    // Add more footnotes as needed
];

// Add the first footnote
if (isset($footnotes[0])) {
    $textrunFootnote1 = $section->addTextRun($paragraphStyle);
    $textrunFootnote1->addText('Here is some text with a footnote.');
    $footnote1 = $textrunFootnote1->addFootnote();
    $footnote1->addText("Footnote 1: " . $footnotes[0], $footercellStyle);
}

// Add additional text to ensure separation between footnotes
$section->addText('Additional text to ensure separation.', null, $paragraphStyle);
$section->addTextBreak();

// Add the second footnote
if (isset($footnotes[1])) {
    $textrunFootnote2 = $section->addTextRun($paragraphStyle);
    $textrunFootnote2->addText('Here is some text with another footnote.');
    $footnote2 = $textrunFootnote2->addFootnote();
    $footnote2->addText("Footnote 2: " . $footnotes[1], $footercellStyle);
}

// Set headers for file download
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="footnote.docx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Pragma: public');

// Create a temporary file in the system's temporary directory
$tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'phpword');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($tempFile);

// Download the file
readfile($tempFile);
unlink($tempFile); // Delete the temp file after downloading
exit;

